# difficulties while using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some website, I however have some difficulties to collect what I want:

```
import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time 

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://cerbios.swiss/news-events/news/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

    

results_date = soup.find(class_='entry-title')

print(results_date)
```

Here is the code that I have, and the output of this code is :

```
<h3 class="entry-title">

<a href="https://cerbios.swiss/new-400-mhz-nmr-in-cerbios/" rel="bookmark" title="NEW 400 MHZ NMR IN 

CERBIOS">NEW 400 MHZ NMR IN CERBIOS</a>

</h3>
```

this is good but what I really want is the "href" in order to have in the output just the URL, I really don't know how to do it, I tried this line  : results_url = soup.find(class_='entry-tite')['href']
but it does not work since the class 'entry-title' does not have the "href" thing.
if anyone can help me it will be a great pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access an `href` attribute on the `<h3>` element which does not exist. You can either keep using `find()` to get to the `<a>` element or use a more specific selector.

```
soup.find(class_='entry-title').find('a')['href']
```

or

```
soup.select_one('h3.entry-title a')['href']
```